# How do you say in a URL the symbol "-"? Slash? Minus? Hyphen?

Tags: symbols

For example: [www.hello-stack.com](http://www.hello-stack.com)

Maybe you say www dot hello slash stack dot com ?

There are several kind of dashes by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Comment: It's called a "dash" according to [this source](https://www.narratorsroadmap.com/how-to-say-web-site-urls-and-email-addresses/#:~:text=The%20period%20in%20a%20web,hyphen%20is%20called%20%E2%80%9Cdash%E2%80%9D.&text=A%20good%20mnemonic%20for%20remembering,be%20RIGHT%20in%20saying%20slash!). "*The period in a web URL or email address is spoken as “dot”. A hyphen is called “dash”.*" However, in quite a few sources that I've seen, "hyphen" and "dash" are used interchangeably.

Comment: That is called a [**hyphen**](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/hyphen).

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment, a hyphen is often mistaken for a dash, which is why I think “dash” is [more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dash%2C+hyphen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chyphen%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chyphen%3B%2Cc0) in daily usage. However, “hyphen” is the correct term to use here (judging by the length of the line) and its usage suggested by @WeatherVane.

Comment: Also, "slash" doesn't make sense here because it is used to denote a "/", not a "-".

Comment: It is definitely not a 'slash'. I prefer 'hyphen' to 'dash' to disambiguate the 'underscore' _ character, but there are several kinds of 'dash' (also the em dash and en dash) making 4 kinds.

Comment: This is an IT question not a grammar one. It's a character in 7-bit ASCII character encodings correctly referred to as a hyphen-minus (because it fulfils both functions in computers with limited character sets). But only a pedant would call it that when reading it out (indeed it would be very confusing). Either hyphen or minus would be fine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus

Comment: I think most techies would call it a "dash".

Comment: I believe there's only one kind of "dash" that [can appear in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942629/1583553), and that's a hyphen.

Comment: To keep increasing the confusion, I could add that dash could be confused with slash if saying quickly? haha